# Can´t INSERT values with Foreign Key in MySQL

Tags: mysql, insert, foreign-keys, innodb, mysql-error-1054

I have a MySQL (5.1.42 on OsX) running.
I added a Foreign Key with this sql statement:

```
ALTER TABLE `Portal`.`Mitarbeiter_2_BlackBerry` 
  ADD CONSTRAINT `fk_Blackberry`
  FOREIGN KEY (`id` )
  REFERENCES `Portal`.`Blackberry` (`id` )
  ON DELETE NO ACTION
  ON UPDATE NO ACTION
, ADD INDEX `fk_Blackberry` (`id` ASC)
```

But when i try to insert values in that table with this sql statement:

```
INSERT INTO Mitarbeiter_2_BlackBerry SET uebergabeAm = '2009-12-01 13:00:00', fk_Blackberry = (SELECT id FROM Blackberry WHERE id = '1')
```

I got the following Error:
Error Code: 1054
Unknown column 'fk_BlackBerry' in 'field list'

Anybody an idea what could be wrong?
Thanks for any hint :-)
Lars.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to put the value in the column `id` not the constraint `fk_Blackerry`. And if you know the value is `1`, just insert `1`- you don't need the subquery.

Answer (score 1):

As per the Syntax Which you you can refer from here.

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/innodb-foreign-key-constraints.html

fk_Blackerry is Symbol, not the column. Column on which foreign key constraint is id, So the updated query should be

INSERT INTO Mitarbeiter_2_BlackBerry SET uebergabeAm = '2009-12-01 13:00:00', id = (SELECT id FROM Blackberry WHERE id = '1')